# Lined-paper line spacing, and redefining the math environment

Tags: amsmath, environments, line-spacing, grid-typesetting, baseline

*(The description is kind of long, questions are at bottom)*

I'm currently using a lined-paper style, thus need all the contents to be strictly sticking to the line.

I've changed the `\baselineskip`, have removed the vertical space of itemized environment using `enumitem` package, and have made some other adjustments, so for now pure text and *most* in-line math look just fine. However, the displayed math always break the correct line spacing. I tried the code below, but this isn't really helping.

```latex
\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
\abovedisplayskip=0pt%
\belowdisplayskip=0pt%
```

To avoid manually fixing using `\vspace{}` every time, I write a "`\protectbox`" macro to produce line spacing of integer multiple of `\baselineskip`, which looks like this:

```latex
\RequirePackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\@temp@length}
\newlength{\protectboxskip}
\newcommand{\protectbox}[2][0]{% the first parameter is an offset of length, the second is the content
    % measure the height of contents
    \setbox0=\vbox{%
        \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
        #2}%
    \@temp@length=\ht0 \advance\@temp@length by \dp0%
    % calculate the number of lines needed to place the content
    \setlength{\@temp@length}{\numexpr\@temp@length/1864679\relax cm + #1\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\protectboxskip}{0.5\@temp@length}%
    \vspace{\protectboxskip}%
    \vspace{-0.3\baselineskip}%
    \par\noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\baselineskip]{\linewidth}%
        \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
        #2%
    \end{minipage}%
    \vspace{\protectboxskip}%
    \vspace{0.3\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother
```

Now I can use `\protectbox` to surround the math environment, so that texts following it are well positioned on the line.

However, sometimes there're so many equations that I want this to be applied automatically. Thus I redefined the `equation` and `equation*` environment as follows:

```latex
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\let\MYequation\equation
\let\endMYequation\endequation
\RenewEnviron{equation}{%
\protectbox[-1]{%
\begin{MYequation}%
    \BODY%
\end{MYequation}}%
}
\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{equation*}{%
\protectbox[-1]{%
\begin{MYequation}%
    \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse% this is copied from amsmath.sty
    \BODY%
\end{MYequation}}%
}
\makeatother
```

These two environments work just fine. However, use of `\[ ... \]` will produce an error (the .log file says it's an "emergency stop", but there's no detail). I find out that `\[ ... \]` is defined by

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

Thus I think it should behave exactly like the `equation*`, but it's not.

I also tried to redefine the `$$ ... $$` since in markdown we usually use this for displayed math and I'm also using the `markdown` package. The code looks like this:

```latex
\catcode`$=\active
\makeatletter
\protected\def${\@ifnextchar$\@doubledollar\@singledollar}
\def\@doubledollar$#1$${\[#1\]}
\def\@singledollar#1${\(#1\)}
\makeatother
```

However the compiler throws an error

```
Package tikz: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and might cause unrecoverable errors.
```

---

Now finally the questions:

**1. (The most important) Is there some cleverer way to solve the lined-paper-style alignment problem? I think my solution for alignment is somewhat ugly, but after a lot of searching, I did not find other solutions.**

**2. Is there some way to integrate the `\protectbox` into math environments `$$ ... $$`, `\[ ... \]`, etc?**

**3. Why does `environment*` work but `\[ ... \]` produce errors?**

Comment: I've added the tag "grid-typesetting" here because that is the recognized name for the layout you are trying to get.  Please add a link to your later question about redefining the math structures; that has been noted as an "XY" question, and adding this information will make it much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As have answered here: [my answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568499), it can be done as follows:

```tex
% \protectbox<optional, space ajust>{optional, height}{content}
\newlength{\protectboxskip}
\NewDocumentCommand\protectbox{D<>{0}om}
{
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
  {% Height not given
    % measure the height
    \setbox0=\vbox{%
    \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
    \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
    \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
    \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
    #3}%
    \@temp@length=\ht0 \advance\@temp@length by \dp0%
    % assign the height
    \setlength{\@temp@length}{\numexpr\@temp@length/\baselineskip\relax\baselineskip + #1\baselineskip}%
  }%
  {% Height given
    \setlength{\@temp@length}{#2\baselineskip-\baselineskip}%
  }
  \setlength{\protectboxskip}{0.5\@temp@length}%
  % space above
  \vspace{\parskip}%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \vspace*{\protectboxskip}%
  \vspace*{-0.2\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{-\parskip}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \par%
  \noindent%
  % the content
  \begin{minipage}[c][\baselineskip]{\linewidth}%
  \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
  \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
  #3%
  \end{minipage}%
  % space after
  \vspace{\protectboxskip}%
  \vspace{0.2\baselineskip}%
}

% Redefine equation and equation*
\let\equation\equation
\let\endequation\endequation
\RenewEnviron{equation}{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\protectbox<0>{%
\begin{equation}%
  \BODY%
\end{equation}}%
\par\noindent%
}
\RenewEnviron{equation*}{%
\protectbox<0>{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\begin{equation}%
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse%
  \BODY%
\end{equation}}%
\par\noindent%
}

% Redefine \[...\]
\def\[#1\]{\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}}
```

This isn't perfect, but it does work. The final result is like this:
[image]