# Integrate some macro into math environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, environments, minipage

For alignment, I write a macro called `\protectbox`, the core part of it is a `minipage` environment. And now every time I write a displayed equation, I have to type:

```latex
\protectbox{%
    \[ ... \]
}
```

However, sometimes I would like to typeset other `.tex` file using my `.cls` style, and I don't want to manually add `\protectbox` to each equation. Thus I begin to think of integrate this macro into the math macro. For `equation` and `equation*`, it really worked:

```latex
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\let\MYequation\equation
\let\endMYequation\endequation
\RenewEnviron{equation}{%
\protectbox[-1]{%
\begin{MYequation}%
    \BODY%
\end{MYequation}}%
}
\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{equation*}{%
\protectbox[-1]{%
\begin{MYequation}%
    \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse% this is copied from amsmath.sty
    \BODY%
\end{MYequation}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, this will cause an error for `\[ ...\]` (the `.log` file says it's an "emergency stop" without further detail).

Also, since many equations come from `markdown` quick notes, formatting in `$$ ... $$`, I would like to integrate `\protectbox` into `$$ ... $$`. But if I do so unproperly, `tikz` will throw an error:

```
Package tikz: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the math-mode dollar sign. This is incompatible with tikz and its calc library and might cause unrecoverable errors.
```

Thus I'm here to ask you. I know it is kind of ugly and dangerous, but for sure, **is there any way to realize this kind of integration**, i.e. plug the `\protectbox` macro into `\[...\]`, `$$...$$`, `equation`, `equation*` without causing serious error?

---

P.S. Here is the current definition of `\protectbox`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\@temp@length}
\newcommand{\protectbox}[2][0]{% the first parameter is an offset of length, the second is the content
    % measure the height of contents
    \setbox0=\vbox{%
        \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
        #2}%
    \@temp@length=\ht0 \advance\@temp@length by \dp0%
    % calculate the number of lines needed to place the content
    \setlength{\@temp@length}{\numexpr\@temp@length/1864679\relax cm + #1\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\protectboxskip}{0.5\@temp@length}%
    \vspace{\protectboxskip}%
    \vspace{-0.3\baselineskip}%
    \par\noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\baselineskip]{\linewidth}%
        \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
        \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
        \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
        #2%
    \end{minipage}%
    \vspace{\protectboxskip}%
    \vspace{0.3\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother
```

---

*I've actually asked this question in [my original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554459), but the original one focused on line spacing, and the problem on mathematical environment was submerged in the long text, thus was not very clearly presented.*

Comment: It might help readers to know the definition of `\protectbox`

Comment: @Segletes Thanks for pointing this out, I've edited my question.

Comment: Since in your self-answer you make it clear that the purpose of this approach to alignment to a grid, you may want to add the term "grid" either in your explanation or as a tag, so this can be found by future searchers for that function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can answer my own question now.

Recall that the meaning of this question is to achieve the following notepaper effect:
[image]

---

Here's how it works.

First, define a `\protectbox` to calculate the height of content (or manually given the height) and make it into a integer multiple of `\baselineskip`, so that the text follows stay right on the line.

```tex
% \protectbox<optional, space ajust>{optional, height}{content}
\newlength{\protectboxskip}
\NewDocumentCommand\protectbox{D<>{0}om}
{
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
  {% Height not given
    % measure the height
    \setbox0=\vbox{%
    \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
    \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
    \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
    \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
    #3}%
    \@temp@length=\ht0 \advance\@temp@length by \dp0%
    % assign the height
    \setlength{\@temp@length}{\numexpr\@temp@length/\baselineskip\relax\baselineskip + #1\baselineskip}%
  }%
  {% Height given
    \setlength{\@temp@length}{#2\baselineskip-\baselineskip}%
  }
  \setlength{\protectboxskip}{0.5\@temp@length}%
  % space above
  \vspace{\parskip}%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \vspace*{\protectboxskip}%
  \vspace*{-0.2\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{-\parskip}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \par%
  \noindent%
  % the content
  \begin{minipage}[c][\baselineskip]{\linewidth}%
  \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt%
  \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
  #3%
  \end{minipage}%
  % space after
  \vspace{\protectboxskip}%
  \vspace{0.2\baselineskip}%
}
```

The next step is integrate this macro into other command or environment, such as `equation`, `table`, `figure`... Begin with `equation`

```tex
% Redefine equation and equation*
\let\equation\equation
\let\endequation\endequation
\RenewEnviron{equation}{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\protectbox<0>{%
\begin{equation}%
  \BODY%
\end{equation}}%
\par\noindent%
}
\RenewEnviron{equation*}{%
\protectbox<0>{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\begin{equation}%
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse%
  \BODY%
\end{equation}}%
\par\noindent%
}
```

then the `\[...\]`:

```tex
% Redefine \[...\]
\def\[#1\]{\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}}
```

and also `table` and `figure` (for the alignment, we would have to make it non-float):

```tex
% Redefine table
% \setlength{\intextsep}{0cm}
\let\FCtable\table
\let\endFCtable\endtable
\RenewEnviron{table}[1][]{%
\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
\FCprotectbox{%
  \def\@captype{table}
  \BODY%
}%
\par\noindent%
}

% Redefine figure
\let\FCfigure\figure
\let\endFCfigure\endfigure
\RenewEnviron{figure}[1][]{%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\FCprotectbox{%
  \def\@captype{figure}
  \BODY%
}%
\par\noindent%
}
```

Finally, it is posible to redefine `$$`, but it is not safe to de so as it may cause error when using `tikz` and its `calc` library. I personally defined an option `safemode` and leave this re-definition below:

```tex
\if@safemode\endinput\fi % This have to be pre-defined

% Redefine $$
\global\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode=\relax
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\def${\@ifnextchar$\@doubledollar\@singledollar}
\def\@doubledollar$#1$${\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}}
\def\@singledollar#1${\(#1\)}
```