# Redefinition of equation* break the \[ ... \], why?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

**EDIT2:** As @Henri commented, this would work: `\def\[#1\]{\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}}`. Thanks for all your kind helping!

**EDIT:** I think I have convinced myself that the current code is enough to produce my desired result. Now I just wonder:

**Why does the following redefinition of `equation*` break the `\[ ... \]`?** With this, the use of `\[ ... \]` will produce bunch of errors.

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\MYequation\equation
\let\endMYequation\endequation
\RenewEnviron{equation*}{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \begin{MYequation}%
      \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse%
      \BODY%
    \end{MYequation}%
\end{minipage}
}
\makeatother
```

Redefining the `\[ ... \]` as below still cannot fix this. I really want to make `\[ ... \]` the same as `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation}`.

```latex
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\[{%
    \begin{equation*}
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\]{%
    \end{equation*}
}%
\makeatother
```

Here's a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\let\MYequation\equation
\let\endMYequation\endequation
\RenewEnviron{equation*}{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \begin{MYequation}%
      \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse%
      \BODY%
    \end{MYequation}%
\end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*} % this is fine
   y^2
\end{equation*}

% \[y^2\]         % this will produce an error

\end{document}
```

---

> **Original question:**
>
> I tried to redefine the math-mode double dollar `$$ ... $$`. Let's
> call this **CODE1**: `` latex \makeatletter \global\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode=\relax \catcode`\$=\active \protected\def${\@ifnextchar$\@doubledollar\@singledollar} \def\@doubledollar$#1$${\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}} \def\@singledollar#1${\(#1\)} \makeatother ``  (*Here the
> `\global\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode=\relax` thing is to
> prevent `tikz` from producing an error.*)
>
> I also redefined the `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`, and
> thus to prevent (*the AMS version of*) `\[ ... \]` from making an
> error, I have to change the definition of `\[ ... \]` from the
> `amsmath.sty` version to the original `ltmath.dtx` version,
> and let's call this **CODE2**: `latex \makeatletter \DeclareRobustCommand\[{%    \relax\ifmmode \@badmath    \else \ifvmode \nointerlineskip \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}% \fi $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK    \fi }% \DeclareRobustCommand\]{%    \relax\ifmmode \ifinner \@badmath \else $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK \fi    \else \@badmath    \fi    \ignorespaces }% \makeatother` 
> **Now here's the question:**
>
> If I write `CODE 2 CODE 1` Then there's no error, but the effect
> (I mean vertical space) of `\[ ... \]` is not the same as `$$ ... $$`. And even if I change CODE2 to the simplified version:
>
> ````latex
>     $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK }% \DeclareRobustCommand\]{%
>     $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK }% \makeatother ``` They still look different. However, if I write ``` CODE 1 CODE 2 ``` Then there's an
> error ``` Paragraph ended before \@doubledollar was complete. ``` Why
> is this happening? Is there any way to achieve this properly?
>
> -----
>
> Below is a MWE: ```latex \documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath}
>
> \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{calc}
>
> % CODE2 \makeatletter \DeclareRobustCommand\[{%    \relax\ifmmode
>       \@badmath    \else
>       \ifvmode
>          \nointerlineskip
>          \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
>       \fi
>       $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK    \fi }% \DeclareRobustCommand\]{%    \relax\ifmmode
>       \ifinner
>          \@badmath
>       \else
>          $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK
>       \fi    \else
>       \@badmath    \fi    \ignorespaces }% \makeatother
>
> % CODE1 \makeatletter \global\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode=\relax
> \catcode`\$=\active
> \protected\def${\@ifnextchar$\@doubledollar\@singledollar}
> \def\@doubledollar$#1$${\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}}
> \def\@singledollar#1${\(#1\)} \makeatother
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \$\$ : $$y^2+\int\mathrm{d} x \frac{p}{q_p^p}$$
>
> $\backslash[ ... \backslash]$ : \[y^2+\int\mathrm{d} x
> \frac{p}{q_p^p}\]
>
> \end{document} ```
> ````

Comment: Classic [XY problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).  What is it that you are *actually* trying to do?  What problem do you think an active `$` is going to solve?

Comment: @Henri, actually I'm trying to make every equation's height an integer multiple of 1cm. And in the way doing so I meet this question.

Comment: I see, and what does this have to do with making `$` active?  I still don't see how that would solve this problem.  Wouldn't it me much easier to hook into `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` to correctly box up these things?

Comment: @Henri, I have actually done the work on `equation` and `equation*` environments. However many of my equations are being written on `markdown` using the `$$ ... $$` format, thus I would like to hook my box into this too.

Comment: @XuJinwen Perhaps you can a) define a new equation environment that accomplish the concrete-height task and b) modify the parser used to output latex from markdown to use that customized equation environment.

Comment: If you are generating LaTeX with pandoc you don't have to use `$$`, but you can just use the `amsmath` environments directly.  Overriding `$$` will not make you happy.

Comment: @Henri, I restated my problem. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: You need to do `\def\[#1\]{\begin{equation*}#1\end{equation*}}` (or something along those lines) for this to work.  The `\begin{equation*}` needs to be able to “see” the `\end{equation*}` by looking ahead without expanding.

Comment: However, I think it is easier to collect the equation in a box and then manipulate the box.  This has other subtleties, but at least doesn't require looking ahead which is always fragile.

Comment: @Henri, Thank you for your previous reply! Perhaps you can describe it in more detail (I don't quite understand your words on box) and make it an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @XuJinwen My ideas are far too vague to write a proper answer.  Maybe something along those lines? http://dpaste.com/24NFGLC7E (expires in 10 days)

Comment: The equation* environment starts with`\csname equation*\endcsname`,  not \equation.  Note that this only applies to environments.

Comment: I believe this question is related to an earlier one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554459 concerning grid typesetting.

Comment: @Barbara Thanks! I will try to make some edit as you said there when I have time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\csdef{[}{\begin{equation*}}
\csdef{]}{\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*} % this is fine
     y^2
  \end{equation*}

  \[y^2\]         % this works too

\end{document}
```

Your MWE does not show any difference between `\[...\]` and the `equation*` environment but I believe that this does what you want with a minimum of technology.

Comment: Nice suggestion `+1`